# guardar informacion del programa en archivos txt

Tags: python, google-api, txt, subida-de-archivos

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que bajo la info una api, pero el proyecto requiere que cuando se vaya el internet todo quede almacenado en un archivo txt para que funcione sin internet, no tengo ni idea como hacerlo.

todo lo descargue de apis, una api de constructores, otra de pilotos otra de carreras, todos en diccionarios, y bueno para el archivo txt tendria que guardar otras lsitas que se crearon en el programa como clientes, etc

Comment: Probaste con el formato json? O mejor, una base de datos? Python ofrece ambas cosas en su librería estandar y sqlite3 no necesita de un server para funcionar.